# Create a card with realtime distance to coordinates

Tags: google-mirror-api

I understand that I can [a render maps](https://developers.google.com/glass/location#rendering_maps_on_timeline_cards) on timeline cards.  Can I create a card with a set of coordinates that display live updates with the distance to those coordinates?

No map is displayed, just a number (meters, feet) that is updated as the user moves.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell that is not possible at the moment.

All you can do with the locations queries are gets and lists. From what I understand it updates every ten minutes as you can read at: https://developers.google.com/glass/location

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a card that contains this information, but it [requires that you use some other APIs in addition to the Mirror API. The Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/) Distance Matrix API appears to be a good fit for this use case.

Every time you'd like to update the timeline card, make a request to the Distance Matrix API to determine the travel distance across that set of coordinates. Convert this into a human readable format, and include it into the `timelineItem.text` or `timelineItem.html` field for the card.

Comment: The Google Distance Matrix API looks useful but it sounds like this process will require regular interaction between my service (calling the Distance Matrix API) and the mirror API to post the card updates.  I need a way to update the **line of sight distance** at least every 5-10 seconds as the person is walking down a trail.  I'd like a to load a series of cards, each with different waypoints.  When the user selects a card, the distance to that waypoint is calculated and updated quickly even if connectivity to my service is lost.

Comment: @SeattleStephens  Got it. That kind of functionality is not available in the Mirror API. Updates to cards always require a round trip.